# whatsapp-web.js + OpenAI API Summarize last 50 messages from groupchat

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

I'm trying to program an Whatsapp bot to summarize the last 50 messages of a specific groupchat using ChatGPT. So far I've built I'm stuck trying to use whatsapp-web.js to extract the last 50 messages to send it to GPT. The route I am attempting is to save those last 50 chats to a json an later send it to GPT. But I'm unable to get those chats out of whatsapp-web.js. Any suggestions on how to reach this final goal is welcomed. Thank you in advance!

```js
const {
  Client,
  LocalAuth
} = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const client = new Client({
  authStrategy: new LocalAuth()
});
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const {
  Configuration,
  OpenAIApi
} = require("openai");
const {
  before
} = require('node:test');
require('dotenv').config()
client.initialize();
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
client.on('qr', (qr) => {
  qrcode.generate(qr, {
    small: true
  });
});
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Client is ready!");
  async function syncMessages(limitmsg) {
    let datafile = [];
    fs.writeFileSync('messages.json', JSON.stringify(datafile));
    const chats = await client.getChats().then((chats) => {
      const myGroup = chats.find(
        (chat) => chat.name === "Leo");
      const mychats = myGroup.fetchMessages({
        limit: 50
      }).then
      console.log(mychats)
      for (const message of mychats) {
        const messageAuthor = message.Author;
        const messageBody = message.body;
        console.log(message);
        console.log(JSON.stringify('From:' + messageAuthor + '-' + messageBody))
        async function readWriteFileJson() {
          var data = fs.readFileSync('messages.json');
          var myObject = JSON.parse(data);
          let newData = {
            messageAuthor: messageAuthor,
            messageBody: messageBody
          };
          await myObject.push(newData);
          await fsPromises.writeFile('messages.json', JSON.stringify(myObject), (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('entry added');
          })
        }
      }
    })
  }
})
//////////////////////////////////////////////

client.on('message', message => {
  console.log(message.body);
  if (message.body.startsWith("Resumo pf")) {
    client.getChats()
      .then(chat = chats.find(
        (chat) => chat.name === "Leo"
      ))
    if (chat.isGroup) {
      const time = message.timestamp()
      fetchMessages({
        after: timestamp - 1000
      })
    }
    runCompletion(message.body.substring(1)).then(result => message.reply(result));
  }
  runCompletion(message.body.substring(1)).then(result => message.reply(result));
});

async function runCompletion(message) {
  const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
    model: "text-davinci-003",
    prompt: message,
    max_tokens: 200,
  });
  return completion.data.choices[0].text;
}
```